# drake abort: Failure at /opt/drake/include/drake/geometry/query_results/contact_surface.h:344 in tri_mesh_W(): condition 'is_triangle()' failed

Tags: drake

I am trying to work on peg-in-hole problem in Drake. The gripper fingers are set to be compliant-hydroelastic using geometry: box for collision and the peg is set to be compliant-hydroelastic using geometry:cylinder for collsion in sdf file. When the gripper fingers about to touch the cylinder peg, meshcat freezes and in the termianl,the following error occurs: abort: Failure at /opt/drake/include/drake/geometry/query_results/contact_surface.h:344 in tri_mesh_W(): condition 'is_triangle()' failed.

I switched back to the gripper sdf provided in the drake example: schunk_wsg_50_no_tip. The error does not occur, but since it is point contact then, the cylinder can move between the two grippers.

Comment: Could you share the drake version that you are using? It'd be also useful if you could provide the call stack at the time the failure occurs.

Comment: The drake version I am using is 1.19.0-1. "abort: Failure at /opt/drake/include/drake/geometry/query_results/contact_surface.h:344 in tri_mesh_W(): condition 'is_triangle()' failed." is all the error information I got when I was running my node. Not sure about which call stack at the time the failure occurs.

Comment: This seems like a bug. It would help me to triage if you could provide the call stack at the time of the failure or even better, the code to reproduce the failure.

Comment: From the include path, it looks like perhaps the call that violates the documented precondition of the `tri_mesh_W()` function is coming from the user's own C++ code, not from within Drake itself.

Comment: If the call is coming from your own C++ code like Jeremy mentioned, then be aware that the default mesh type for the hydroelastic contact is polygon mesh, so you shouldn't be calling tri_mesh_W(). Use poly_mesh_W() instead. You can change the hydro contact mesh type in the MultibodyPlantConfig: https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/structdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant_config.html#a662fe783b3fe8423c76e73ea8910a544